buttons created by iterating a list only saving the last position id
I have a list of Items, called Topics, that contain several props, including id.
LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
    modifier = Modifier.padding(padding),
) {
    items(topicsList) { topic ->
        TopicItem(
            topic,
            topicsViewModel,
            navController,
            sheetState,
            isMenuVisible,
            toggleMenuVisibility = { toggleMenuVisibility() },
        )
    }
}

The TopicItem:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TopicItem(
    topic: Topic,
    topicsViewModel: TopicViewModel,
    navController: NavController,
    sheetState: SheetState,
    isMenuVisible: Boolean,
    toggleMenuVisibility: () -> Unit,
) {
    val topicId = remember { mutableStateOf(topic.id) }

    Text(
        text = topic.name + topicId.value,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium,
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
    )

    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        onClick = {
            if (!sheetState.isVisible) {
                toggleMenuVisibility()
            }
            navController.navigate("edit_topic/${topicId.value}")
        },
    ) {
        Text(text = "Edit")
    }

    Button(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(bottom = 24.dp),
        onClick = {
            try {
                topicsViewModel.deleteTopic(topicId.value)
                toggleMenuVisibility()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                print(e.message)
            }
        },
    ) {
        Text(text = "Delete")
    }
}

The information is rendered correctly but the issue that i face is that when i click on the buttons they use the id of the last item on the topicsList and not the one that was used to render the item.
How can i solve this?

Although I don't know why topicId is a mutable state or why that variable is even needed (all usages of topicId.value could be safely replaced by topic.id), the code seems to work as intended, I cannot reproduce your problem. Can you expand your example so it can be executed and reproduces the problem? A minimal reproducible example would be needed.
